# Poco::DirectoryWatcher no notification for DW_ITEM_MODIFIED

Tags: c++, poco

try to figure out how to use **Poco::DirectoryWatcher**.
Unfortunately, it is not working like expected.
When i add a file to the watch folder,  delegate **onFileAdded** is called then
delegate **onFileChanged**.
From this point silence. When i change the newly added file or any other,
delegate **onFileChanged** is not called.

Compiled on a Windows 10 64 bit (VMWare WS guest on Windows 10 46 bit host).
Compiled with VS 2022, static linkage.  Poco (1.11.1) libarary linked from vcpkg.

This is my source code simplyfied.

```
Poco::File dir("c:\\test");
std::shared_ptr<DirectoryWatcher> watcher;
watcher.reset(new Poco::DirectoryWatcher(dir, Poco::DirectoryWatcher::DW_ITEM_ADDED | Poco::DirectoryWatcher::DW_ITEM_MODIFIED, 5));

watcher->itemAdded += Poco::delegate(this, &tcDirectoryWatcher::onFileAdded);
watcher->itemAdded += Poco::delegate(this, &tcDirectoryWatcher::onFileChanged);
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling scans for everything with `DW_FILTER_ENABLE_ALL`?

Comment: DW_FILTER_ENABLE_ALL is not fixing this. Still get no changed event when i changed file. Notepad++ detects this change.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i addded the OnFileChanged to itemAdded delegate.
The correct code is:

```
    Poco::File dir("c:\\test");
std::shared_ptr<DirectoryWatcher> watcher;
watcher.reset(new Poco::DirectoryWatcher(dir, Poco::DirectoryWatcher::DW_ITEM_ADDED | Poco::DirectoryWatcher::DW_ITEM_MODIFIED, 5));

watcher->itemAdded += Poco::delegate(this, &tcDirectoryWatcher::onFileAdded);
watcher->itemModified+=Poco::delegate(this,&tcDirectoryWatcher::onFileChanged);
```